# copy lines from file to list

Tags: python

I need to write a function that read from a file and put every some lines as one cell in a list.
I need to copy the lines between 1 to 2 and from 2 to the end and put each of them in different cell in the list, without the lines that contains the number and empty lines.
I dont have an idea how make it work.

the file:

```
; 1

####
# .#
#  ###
#*@  #
#  $ #
#  ###
####

; 2

######
#    #
# #@ #
# $* #
# .* #
#    #
######
```

my code:

```
def loader(filename):
    levels=[[]]
    f=open(filename, "r")
    x=[]
    for line in f:
        if ";" not in line:
            x.append(line)
        else:
            levels.append(x)
    f.close()
    return levels
```

output:
cell 1:

```
####
# .#
#  ###
#*@  #
#  $ #
#  ###
####
```

cell 2:

```
######
#    #
# #@ #
# $* #
# .* #
#    #
######
```

Comment: What do you want your end list to look like?

Comment: I dont have an expected output to show for example,but I added something to my post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Final best solution:

If you use `re`, you can find anything from

```
; 1
```

to

```
;    2
```

Here's the code:

```
import re
levels = [x[2:].strip() for x in re.split(';\s*\d', open(filename).read()) if x != '']
```

older: (compensates for numbers, and gets rid of blank lines completely)

```
levels = [x[2:].strip() for x in open(filename).read().split(';') if x != '']
```

OR

```
levels = [x[1:].strip() for x in open(filename).read().split('; ') if x.strip() != '']
```

To print the output:

```
for level in levels:
    print level
```

Or individually:

```
print levels[0]
print levels[1]
```

Comment: but its still copy empty lines, no?
and you have any idea how to rid from the numbers? I tried rstrip(int) but there is no such thing

Comment: If you want to exclude lines with numbers and blank lines, add `if line.strip().strip('\n') != '' and not line.isdigit()` before the `print` statement.

Comment: yes it's!
can you explain what the difference pls?
can I remove a cell that contain only "" with levels.remove("")?

Comment: How about now? I didnt quite understand what you were asking though

Comment: its worked with the x[2:].forget about what I asked, I got it.
but I dont understand what the x[2:] do..can you explain?

Comment: `x[]` is called `slicing`. It's sort of like a `range`; it only takes the part specified. In `x[2:]` it's taking most of `x`, starting at the 3rd character. Read about it [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#slice).

Comment: so its won't help if the number place in the 5th charcter for example

Comment: And also, on [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/509295/1313757) is some very good examples of this.

Comment: @user1816377 You're right, it would have to be the 3rd every time.

Comment: tnx for your help @yentup!!

Comment: @user1816377 Wait! I made it so it can find `;` and any number of spaces, and then a number, `1`. Try that code and see if it works.

Answer (score 2):

Give this a shot:

```
def loader(filename):
  levels,x = [],[]
  for line in open(filename,'r'):
    line = line.strip('\n').strip()

    # Skip blank lines
    if line == '':
      continue

    # Assuming that lines containing ';' mark a new cell, so save the old cell
    if ';' in line:
      if x != []:
        levels.append(x)
      x = []

    # If the line doesn't contain ';', it is part of the current cell
    else:
      x.append(line)

  # Save the last cell, if there was one
  if x != []:
    levels.append(x)
  return levels


cells = loader("testfile")
```

You can build the output for the Nth cell with `cell_output = '\n'.join(cell[n-1])`:

`print '\n'.join(cells[0])` prints your "output cell 1" from above

Answer (score 2):

```
from itertools import groupby as gb

with open(file,'r') as f:
   [list(g) for k,g in gb(f.readlines(),lambda x:';'in x or x=='\n') if not k]
```

Out:

```
[[u'####\n',
  u'# .#\n',
  u'#  ###\n',
  u'#*@  #\n',
  u'#  $ #\n',
  u'#  ###\n',
  u'####\n'],
 [u'######\n',
  u'#    #\n',
  u'# #@ #\n',
  u'# $* #\n',
  u'# .* #\n',
  u'#    #\n',
  u'######\n']]
```